# Could not install package

Tags: xamarin

Could not install package 'Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8 1.6.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: that package requires Mono.Android 12

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that by targeting Android 12.

Change:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v11.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

To:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v12.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

This has to be done in all your Android projects, including Library projects.

Make sure your Xamarin.Android tooling is up to date, along with having API 32 installed in your Android SDK manager.

Also don't get fooled by the `AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk` property if you do not have the correct SDK installed. It will just grab the latest you have installed and if that is lower than 12, you will still have the issue.

Also make sure to restore NuGet packages after this change.